# Auto add a class instance to an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, class

How can I auto add a new class instance to an array?

**Example:**

```
class Product {
    var name: String?
}

var products = [Product]()
```

How can I add a new instance of a Product class to the products Array? How can I append to the array?

I tried some code but I don't know how to reference the class in own class.

I tried something like this:

```
class Product {
    var name: String?

    init() {
        products.append(Produt)
    }

    var products = [Product]()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `self` to get a reference to itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your newly created object stored in `products` array then you need to declare it as `static` property so that it is shared by all instance otherwise it will just add first object for your every instance.

```
class Product {
    var name: String?
    static var products = [Product]()

    init() {
        Product.products.append(self)
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        Product.products.append(self)
    } 
}
```

Now use this `products` array using `Product.products`.

```
_ = Product(name: "One")
_ = Product(name: "two")
print(Product.products)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `products.append(self)` ?

Answer (score 2):

I dont't know why you need it, but you can use

```
class Product {
    static var products: [Product] = []

    var name: String?

    init() {
        products.append(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access `static` property directly, it is only access through `classname`.