# Swift - auto add a class instance to an array when initialising

Tags: swift, xcode

My code is setup in the following way:

```
class MyClass {

    let text: String

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }  

}

var items = [MyClass]()

let item = MyClass(text: "sometext")
```

The idea is to get **item** into the **items** array, such as with:

```
items.append(item)
```

The main problem with this is that I initialise these items in a swift file, and I would get the error
*Expressions are not allowed at the top level*
Also, I'd prefer not to use this somewhere such as viewDidLoad() because there may be too many MyClass items.

I've tried this

```
class MyClass {

    let text: String

    static var items = [MyClass]()

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        MyClass.items.append(self)
    }  

}
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141962/auto-add-a-class-instance-to-an-array-in-swift)

However, after intialising several **MyClass** objects, **items** is still empty.

Is there any way I can do this?

EDIT: thank you for the suggestions so far. These were typos (using **item** rather than **self**, and **items**, rather than **MyClass.items**. This is how I've used it in my code. It compiles & still doesn't work, sadly.

Comment: Perhaps its a typo, but you need `items.append(self)`

Comment: Are you using `items` as `MyClass.items`? You should use that.

Comment: Indeed, they were typos. Thanks for pointing that out! I've edited the post

Comment: In that case why are you doing this `var items = [MyClass]()` you already have `MyClass.items`. That is all you need to use. If you do `var items = [MyClass]()`, that will be completely different array than `MyClass.items` and count will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not compile. This is the error-free code for the class.

```
class MyClass {

    let text: String

    static var items = [MyClass]()

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        MyClass.items.append(self)
    }

}
```

The two things that were wrong in your code.

- You should be appending `self` to `items`, because `self` is the instance of `Item` that you create which is available inside `init`.
- *static* methods should be accessed with their **class name**.

Example:

```
let blah = MyClass(text: "blah")
let bleh = MyClass(text: "bleh")

print(MyClass.items.count) // Prints 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I've made the correction in the post. This is actually how I've set it up in my code, but I made the typo when posting here. I've included everything in your answer, but the array count is still 0, unfortunately.

Comment: @RyanBenschop can you show all the rest of your code?

Comment: @RyanBenschop ?